# Android: как программно вызвать окно выбора метода ввода?

Tags: android, java

Нужно в коде программы вызвать окно выбора метода ввода. Как это можно сделать? Если через intent-фильтры, то по какому слову?

Поясняю:
У меня есть edittext, в котором я осуществляю перехват нажатия с помощью onTouch. В методе OnTouch я вызываю клавиатуру и выполняю еще несколько действий. Однако, пропала возможность выбора метода ввода при долгом нажатии на edittext. Вот, пытаюсь ее вернуть.

Код:

```
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        et.setOnTouchListener(this);

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

                Answer.super.onTouchEvent(me); //Пытаюсь обработать нажатие по обычному, но безуспешно
                if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN & v.getId() == R.id.answer) {
                      Answer.super.onTouchEvent(me);

                      EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
                      // Показ клавиатуры
                      InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)     
                      getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                      imm.showSoftInput(et, 0);

     //Как раз то, ради чего создавался OnTouch:            
((LockableScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll)).setScrollingEnabled(true);
                    return true;
                } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Answer.super.onTouchEvent(me);              ((LockableScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll)).setScrollingEnabled(true);              
                    return true;
                }
                Answer.super.onTouchEvent(me);          
                return false;   
            }
```

Comment: не совсем понятно что ты хочешь сделать, выбор можно через диалог - поясни что хочешь сделать

Comment: > В методе OnTouch я вызываю клавиатуру

зачем?

Comment: Потому что мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию на EditText выполнялись все стандартные действия + еще несколько(для чего мне и пришлось перехватывать нажатие с помощью OnTouch). Если я ее не вызову программно, то она вообще не вызовется.

Comment: покажи лучше код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл-таки решение: вызов окна выбора метода ввода вызывается всего лишь одной строчкой кода:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
          imm.showInputMethodPicker();
```

Answer (score 1):

мда, код желает быть лучше =)

```
 EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        et.setOnTouchListener(this);

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

   //             Answer.super.onTouchEvent(me); //Пытаюсь обработать нажатие по обычному, но безуспешно - это совсем не по обычному, так как у тебя слушатель прицеплен только к одной View, будет обрабатываться то что надо.

                if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    //                  Answer.super.onTouchEvent(me); непонятно зачем

        //              EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer); зачем еще раз искать его??
                      // Показ клавиатуры
          //            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)     
            //          getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
              //        imm.showSoftInput(et, 0); сама должна выехать

     //Как раз то, ради чего создавался OnTouch:    это я даже не представляю что такое )        
((LockableScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll)).setScrollingEnabled(true);
                    return true;
                } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Answer.super.onTouchEvent(me);         ((LockableScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll)).setScrollingEnabled(true);

                    return true;
                } //                    Answer.super.onTouchEvent(me);         тоже лишнее
                return false;

 }
```

Comment: При таком коде вообще ничего не работает - ни длинное нажатие, ни короткое. То есть клавиатура не показывается, выбор метода ввода не вызывается.
А Answer.super.onTouchEvent(me) я везде напихал, думал, может, хоть в одном месте передаст обработку на обычный клик по EditText, но нет.

Comment: значит ошибка в другом месте, у меня в примере, если выкинуть все комментарии, то метод должен отрабатывать, попробуй переписать на 

et.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {....);